# Magento loading wrong css on product page

Tags: magento

On other pages of websites the css path is

http://xxx/magento_raw/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css

But on product page it is

http://xxx/magento_raw/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css

Why magento is taking css from base folder on product page.

Comment: when magento not find valid path from your css this one display using base theme. use this one

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13974/why-my-css-is-loading-from-the-base-theme-instead-of-custom-theme-on-migrating-t

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *Settings -> Configuration - General -> Design* then set the Design Tab accordingly to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

please use this code
 your theme/layout/etc/theme.xml

```
<theme>
    <parent>yourtheme/default</parent>
</theme>
```

use your theme name than it will access css file from your theme...